# How to slow a function that types a random string from an array when it comes across a period or comma?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a typewriter function as such:

```js
var myArray = [
  'sentence. another sentence.', 
  'this sentence. yet another sentence.', 
];
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
var i = 0;
var speed = 55;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < rand.length) {
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML += rand.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<div id="question"></div>
```

How can I have the typewriter function speed change to say, 80ms, if the character it's currently typing is a period or comma, then return to 55ms when it's typing normal letters? This would help me to imitate the rhythm of speech with the typing function and improve readability. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a variable called `speed`, so why not change its value when the current character is a comma or a period? (Don't forget to change it back later!).

```js
var myArray = ['sentence. another sentence.', 
              'this sentence. yet another sentence.', 
           ];
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
var i = 0;
var speed = 55;
  function typeWriter() {
    if (i < rand.length) {
      document.getElementById("question").innerHTML += rand.charAt(i);
 
    if(rand.charAt(i) == '.' || rand.charAt(i) == ',') {
      speed = 1000;
    }
    else {
      speed = 85;
    }
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<p id="question"></p>
```

Comment: @HelloWorld Note that Java isn't Javascript! (`Java != JS`)

Answer (score 1):

Just change `speed` or the 2nd param to `setTimeout`.

While you're at it, you may as well make the code cleaner by:

1) using `await` instead of `setTimeout`,

2) name your delays (e.g. `DELAYS`) as opposed to a bunch of inline constants

3) use a proper for loop instead of a reinventing the for loop with if statements

4) use proper local variables and function params instead of global variables.

5) Use `Element.textContent` instead of `innerHTML`

6) Use single quotes in JS unless necessary to do otherwise.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('div');

let wait = delay => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay));

let typeWriter = async sentence => {
  const DELAYS = {'.': 500, ',': 200, default: 55};

  for (let c of sentence) {
    el.textContent += c;
    await wait(DELAYS[c] || DELAYS.default);
  }
};

typeWriter('sentence. a comma, another sentence. this sentence. yet another sentence.');
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Great answer, but I'm not clear on the point of adding the promise here. Can you explain how it's better than just inlining the `setTimeout` call and skipping the whole `wait` function? Thanks!

Comment: *"use a proper for loop instead of a reinventing the for loop with if statements"*. There's something in life called recursion.

Comment: @AnisR. Recursion is appropriate when it is cleaner than alternatives. All for, while and other loops can be rewritten as recursion but doing so isn't always the right choice.

Comment: @ggorlen, promises were motivated as a way to avoid callbacks. There's extensive discussion as to why callbacks are problematic; put shortly, callbacks are harder to maintain and reason about than promises. So the latter are preferred by default when there's no compelling reason otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the current character inside `typeWriter`, and set the next character's timeout accordingly.

To achieve this, it's practical to use the [conditional (ternary) operator (`? :`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var myArray = ['sentence. another sentence.', 
              'this sentence. yet another sentence.', 
           ];
var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
var i = 0;
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < rand.length) {
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML += rand.charAt(i);
    setTimeout(typeWriter, ['.', ','].includes(rand.charAt(i)) ? 80 : 55);
    i++
  }
}
```

Comment: The idea makes sense to me. What is the significance of 80:55 at the end of the setTimeout? Does that make it conditional; if period or comma then the timeout is 80, if not, the timeout is 55?

Comment: @HelloWorld this is called a ternary operator. It's like a shorthand for an if/else block. Look it up, it can be pretty handy at times!

Comment: @HelloWorld Yes, the `? :` is the conditional operator in JS, it takes the form of `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`. `['.',','].includes(rand.charAt(i))` checks whether the current character is in the list (i.e. is comma or dot).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it (makes it more modular, also in ES6 style)

```js
const typeWriter = (str, writeTo, charDelays) => {
  if (!str) return; // Empty
  const nextChar = str.charAt(0);
  writeTo.textContent += nextChar;
  setTimeout(
    () => typeWriter(str.slice(1), writeTo, charDelays), // typeWriter rest of the string
    charDelays[nextChar] || charDelays.DEFAULT || 55 // Custom delay per character
  );
}
```

Then you can do this:

```js
typeWriter('my, very awesome, string!?', document.getElementById('question'), {
  '!': 80,
  ',': 80
});
```